# route not found 404 codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an app with some routes, but I'm having an error when including a parameter

```
$route['contato'] = '/contato';
$route['contato/(:num)']['GET'] = '/contato/$1';
$route['contato/(:num)']['PUT'] = 'contato/update/$1';
$route['contato/(:num)']['DELETE'] = 'contato/delete/$1';
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = '';

        $id = $this->input->get('id')

        if (isset($id)) {
            $data = $this->contato_model->get($id);
        } else {
            $data = $this->contato_model->get();
        }
        echo $this->ultils->toJson($data);
    }
```

More when accessing the api `https://localhost/api/contact/1` via url

Give error not found (404)

Return of just one record, if I change the code to ?=id and pass it in the url contato?id=2 it works, I need it to be that way in the /contato/2 route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `config/routes.php` you need to specify which function call within the class:

```
$route['contato'] = '/contato/index';
$route['contato/(:num)']['GET'] = '/contato/index/$1';
```

and the function should look like this:

```
public function index($id = false) {
    $data = '';
    
    if (is_numeric($id)) {
        $data = $this->contato_model->get($id);
    } else {
        $data = $this->contato_model->get();
    }

    echo $this->ultils->toJson($data);
}
```

**Passing URI Segments to your methods**

If your URI contains more than two segments they will be passed to your method as parameters.

For example, let’s say you have a URI like this:

```
example.com/index.php/products/shoes/sandals/123
```

Your method will be passed URI segments 3 and 4 (“sandals” and “123”):

```php
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {
    public function shoes($category, $id) {
        echo $category;
        echo $id;
        }
}
```

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods